# Convert latitude and longitude to x and y coordinates on a canvas (Java)?

Tags: java, dictionary, latitude-longitude

I have a set of latitude and longitude points in decimal form for a city and I need to convert them to x and y coordinates in order to draw them on a canvas and find the distance between them. I am confused as to what the formula for this would be, any help would be appreciated. I don't need to account for the curvature of the Earth as it's just a flat map.

Thanks

Comment: *it's just a flat map* -- It's really not that simple. Read up on [map projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection).

Answer (score 1):

Since Longitude and Latitude Co-ordinates are co-ordinates for a *spherical* shape, it is just not a matter of transposing them from one point to another. As pointed out [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system), you will need to take into account certain factors.

My recommendation would be to take a look at [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/) products, especially the `JXMapViewer`. Take a look at [this](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com/2007/11/building-maps-into-your-swing.html) tutorial, it should help you out with what you need.